# Slant Physics Raycast Implementation

Tags: unity-game-engine

For my 3d car game, I was doing Physics raycast to detect obstacles and based on detect take turn left or right side. Currently, I was doing straight raycast and I can't able to detect left and right side existed obstacles.

So I decided to do little bit slant raycast to detect something from the left and right side.
The following image explains a better way my question:
[image]

This code is running at present:

```
    Ray rayRight = new Ray(thisTransform.position + Vector3.up * 0.2f + thisTransform.right * detectAngle * 0.5f + transform.right * detectAngle * 0.0f * Mathf.Sin(Time.time * 50), transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward) * detectDistance);
    Ray rayLeft = new Ray(thisTransform.position + Vector3.up * 0.2f + thisTransform.right * -detectAngle * 0.5f - transform.right * detectAngle * 0.0f * Mathf.Sin(Time.time * 50), transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward) * detectDistance);

    Debug.DrawRay(rayRight.origin, rayRight.direction * detectDistance, Color.red);
    Debug.DrawRay(rayLeft.origin, rayLeft.direction * detectDistance, Color.red);
```

Now please give me a guidance to do slant physics raycast to detect obstacles.

Comment: What do you mean for "slant"?

Comment: I want to detect left and right side obstacle because AI cars quickly taking turn so continuous result require before they take turn....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a differnt direction than Vector3.forward?

Define two Vector3 fields in your class (names below are suggestions), then in `Start()` initalize them like

```cs
float angle = 15.0f //or whatever you need.
leftRayDirection = Quaternion.AngleAxis(-angle, Vector3.up) * Vector3.forward;
rightRayDirection = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, Vector3.up) * Vector3.forward;
```

and use those instead of just Vector3.foward (ofc you still need to transform them, with transform.transformDirection).

Or if you want them to sweep, just calculate them in `Update()`.

edit:
Another option would be to store the 2 Quaternions in a field and use them to rotate `transform.forward` (which is the same as `transform.transformDirection(Vector3.forward)`) like.

```cs
//Field
Quaternion leftRayRotation;

//in Start()
leftRayRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(-angle, Vector3.up);

//before Raycasting
Ray leftRay = new Ray(transform.position + leftRayOffset, leftRayRotation * transform.forward);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply - I will check the above suggestion and reply back to you.