# raycasting at an angle in 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am having a lot trouble trying to shoot a raycast at an angle.  I know its simple but all of the examples i find online just dont work for me.  Here is an example of my code

```
RaycastHit2D Hit = Physics2D.Raycast(firepoint.position, firepoint.right);
```

The firepoint is the object attached to the player and is where the gun will fire from. with the debug i can see that the raycast does draw at 90 degrees but im stuck because i need it to draw at 45 degrees.  How would i go about changing this? thanks in advance!

EDIT:

```
    Quaternion leftRayRotation;
  leftRayRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(45, Vector3.up);       
     Debug.DrawRay(firepoint.position, leftRayRotation * firepoint.forward, Color.green);
```

Comment: Well, `firepoint.right` as the name suggests, points to the right side at 90°. You'll need to construct a vector that points in the direction you want. I answered a similar question here, hope it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57417158/slant-physics-raycast-implementation/57417351#57417351

Comment: okay so i have got this and it doesnt, but i get where you are coming from, ill put the edited answer on the post